# Counting the amount of occurrences in a sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, frequency, find-occurrences

I have a sorted array that is given to me from the user and I'm passing it to the function `countOccurences` along with the size of the array and the integer `x` is in a for-loop in the main program running from 0 to the maximum value in the set of integers in the array. For some reason when I do this I get the wrong answer. Like if I enter 4, 5, 5, and 15 I get the following result below:

```
void countOccurneces(int data[], int SizeOfArray, int x)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfArray; i++)
        if (x == data[i])
            res++;
    if (res > 0)
        cout << res << " for number " << x << endl;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5HF2.png)

Comment: Can you show where you calling this function? And exactly what X is?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @imanshu15 all that really matters is that data[] is a sorted array and x is coming from a for loop that is calling it that is going from 0 to the maximum value in the array

Comment: 1 for number 4
2 for number 5
2 for number 5
1 for number 15 .. @BrycePurnell Is this ur required output?

Comment: How certain are you that `SizeOfArray` contains a valid value?

Comment: works for me: https://ideone.com/nIa6aL Your problem is elsewhere, please provide an MCVE

Comment: If `data` is sorted, you can count occurrences more efficiently: `std::distance(std::lower_bound(data, data + N, x), std::upper_bound(data, data + N, x))`. (or using `std::equal_range`).